# How to sort the list having float values in python?

Tags: python, list, csv, sorting

I have output like -

```
x1 = [['10.0', '[9.8-10.2]'], ['10.4', '[10.0-10.8]'], ['10.9', '[8.7-13.7]'], ['102.3', '[96.1-108.9]'], ['107.8', '[99.5-116.9]'], ['108.4', '[98.1-119.6]'], ['109.9', '[100.6-120.7]'], ['11.0', '[10.8-11.2]'], ['11.1', '[10.5-11.7]'], ['11.2', '[10.9-11.5]'], ['11.2', '[11.0-11.4]'], ['11.3', '[10.6-12.0]'], ['11.6', '[11.4-11.9]'], ['110.7', '[97.9-125.9]'], ['117.3', '[108.8-126.2]'], ['118.1', '[106.1-130.8]'], ['119.4', '[102.9-137.8]'], ['12.2', '[11.5-12.9]'], ['12.6', '[12.3-12.9]']]
```

This is after sort but it is returning 10.0, 10.4, 10.9, 102.3, 107.8, 108.4, 109.9, 11.0,11.1 and so on but it should be like this- 10.0, 10.4, 10.9, 11.0,11.1, 102.3, 107.8, 108.4, 109.9

What i tried is below:

```
for x3 in ss:
    if x3[0].isdigit():
        ss = float(x3[0])

x1 = sorted(ss, key = itemgetter(0))
print x1
```

The above output is of x1.

Even without using isdigit() and float(), output is same.
    x1 = sorted(ss, key = itemgetter(0))
    print x1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for your problem:

```
sorted(x1, key=lambda x: float(x[0]))
```

I assumed your sorting function didn't work and that ss is actually equal to x1. In either case what you want to do is to pass a function to the key param in the `sorted()` function.

This key should be the first element as float (hence the `float(x[0])`)

Comment: please, explain him why. Otherwise he will be asking some other question about how to do it with integers in two weeks ;)

Comment: This one really worked. Thankyou so much :)

Comment: @Netwave - I know how did it work. :)

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to convert the first element of your sublists to `float` and then use `sorted`. This does mutate your original sublists, but may be precisely what you need.

```
res = sorted(map(lambda i: [float(i[0]), i[1]], x1))
```

Here we take each sublist and convert the first element to `float`, while keeping the second element unchanged.

---

If you wish to use `itemgetter` and avoid `lambda`, the easiest way is to compose functions. This isn't available in the standard library, but [`toolz`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.functoolz.compose) offers this functionality:

```
from toolz import compose
from operator import itemgetter

res = sorted(x1, key=compose(float, itemgetter(0)))
```

Comment: toolz is really new for me. Thankyou so much. I was thinking to use float with itemgetter() but did not know that we can give 2 arguments like this.

Comment: @garg, Yep. But beware, it's a 3rd party library, so not fully portable. In my opinion, composition is so fundamental to functional programming that it should be in `functools` at least.

Comment: .......@jpp - Ok!